# dhtmlx-gantt - angular cli - localizing

Tags: angular-cli, angular5, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

I'm struggling with the localization of the dhtmlx-gantt-5.0.5 chart. I'm running an Angular 5 app which is generated with @angular/cli-1.6.3.

In the dhtmlx-gantt docs it says that the script should be added as shown in the image below.
https://i.imgur.com/WhJwL5I.png

I tried doing this in my index.html, but the chart is still rendered in English.
I've also tried to include locale_nb.js and locale_nb.js.map in the scripts array of my angular-cli.json, with no success.
https://i.imgur.com/Ki8SzqA.png

Does anyone know how this could be done with angular-cli?

Comment: Found the solution. Simply just import the locale file at the top of the component.

import 'dhtmlx-gantt/codebase/locale/locale_nb.js';